# Getting errors after changing HTML file to PHP

Tags: php, html

I changed my  html file to php in order to show php errors in form , I wasn't sure if I suppose to add or reduce php/html tags. I left  as it is. When I open my form in browser its showing me the following errors. :

> Notice: Undefined variable: name_error in C:\xampp\htdocs\BootstrapLandinPage\index.php on line 165
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: lastname_error in C:\xampp\htdocs\BootstrapLandinPage\index.php on line 170
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: phone_error in C:\xampp\htdocs\BootstrapLandinPage\index.php on line 175

and etc.

Basically every input showing an error.

My index.php:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--NAVIGATION-->

        <div id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ">Hello Dolly</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainpanel">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                        <li><a href="#header">dolly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">holly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#pricing">holly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team">holly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#client">holly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">holly</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--- Header ---->
 <section class="parallax">
                <div class="parallax-inner">
        <div id="header" class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 wow bounceInLeft navbar-right">
                        <h1 class="text-right" id="main-title">dolly </h1>
                        <h2 class="text-right" id="changed-title">dolly</h2><br><br>
                        <!---   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary navbar-right">dolly</button> ---->

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
 </section>

            <!-- [CONTACT] -->
           <section class="inspiration" id="three">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <article class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <div class="intermediate-container">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h2>יש לכם שאלה? צרו איתי קשר</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 center-block col-sm-6 ">
                                            <form id="mc-form" action ="send.php" method="POST">
                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label for="name" hidden >שם פרטי</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="cv form-control" value="<?= $name ?>" placeholder="שם פרטי" >
                                                     <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label for="lastName" hidden>שם משפחה</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="cv form-control" value="<?= $lastName ?>" placeholder="שם משפחה" >
                                                     <span class="error"><?= $lastname_error ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label for="phone" hidden>טלפון</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="cv form-control" value="<?= $phone ?>" placeholder="טלפון" >
                                                     <span class="error"><?= $phone_error ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label for="email" hidden>דואר אלקטרוני</label>
                                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="cv form-control" value="<?= $email ?>" placeholder="דואר אלקטרוני" >
                                                     <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label for="subject" hidden>נושא</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="cv form-control" value="<?= $subject?>" placeholder="נושא" >
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label for="message" hidden>הודעה</label>
                                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="cv form-control message"  placeholder="השאירו את הודעתכם פה" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-custom-outline " value="שלח" >
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>
                                                <!--<span class="error"></span> -->
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </section>
            <!-- [/CONTACT] -->




        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
           <!-- [ SLIDER SCRIPT ] -->  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

send.php:

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $lastname_error = $email_error = $phone_error = "";
$name = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zא-ת ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["lastName"])) {
    $lastname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zא- ]*$/",$lastName)) {
      $lastname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phone_error = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
      $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
  }

if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subject = "";
  } else {
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $lastname_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'ilonasemyweb@gmail.com';
      $subjectm = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subjectm, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: You put some of the variables in uppercase.  Case is important in PHP  ex : `$lastName_error != $lastname_error`

Comment: It literally tells you your problem in the error message. Your variables aren't defined. Check if they are and only then echo them

Comment: Defining variables in send.php will not make them available in index.php.

Comment: @SourceOverflow I defined them i send.php , not in index.php. I got an error in inex.php where i have my form with form action to send.php

Comment: @Don'tPanic where exactly in index.php I should define them?

Comment: It looks like the form in index.php submits to send.php. You can store them in the session in send.php and then redirect back to index.php, where you read them back from the session (if they exist).

Comment: @Don'tPanic can you please demonstrate with an actual code, I don't know how to work with sessions very well

Comment: @SemSam added an answer with a brief example.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:

1. In `index.php`: Check if those variables are defined. If not, then there are no errors, so display nothing of that sorts, just as it would be on first entry.
2. In `send.php`: Properly send back `index.php` on error. This can be done using the `require_once` method.

So after checking all sent data for errors write:

```
if(/* there were errors */)
  require_once("path/to/index.php");
```

This will then get all the text from `index.php`, "put it in that place in index.php" and continue interpreting. Using this, all variables defined in `send.php` are now also defined in `index.php` (and retain their values, of course). Note however that the new url will now end with `send.php`, unless you trick around that a bit.

Comment: I didn't  understand the first answer ,I guess they not defined since I getting an error.What do you mean by " If not, then there are no errors, so display nothing of that sorts, just as it would be on first entry." Can you please specify?Thank you

Comment: If the variables aren't defined, then there are no errors. Just make the checks around the whole error element (error-wrappers etc.). Don't make empty error boxes.